# Why didn't R2-D2 and/or C-3PO spill the beans?

Tags: star-wars, droids, r2-d2, c-3po

In the prequels we see that both C3PO and R2D2 are Anakin's droids and they clearly both know that he's gone over to the dark side.

I would like to know an *in-universe* answer for the question; Why did they not tell Luke?

> that Vader is Anakin?

Comment: Leia was a baby and was seporated from her brother, They knew lukes heritage because he kept the last name Skywalker. Im asking why they never told Luke that Anikan his father is Vader

Comment: From [Wookiepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/R2-D2): `Although R2-D2's inability to speak basic spared him from experiencing a memory wipe, it did undergo reprogramming to restrict access to the holo-recordings of Leia's birthparents, including Skywalker choking Amidala and her deathbed during delivery, to ensure that Leia's true parentage remained a secret.` Maybe this also prevented him from telling Luke about Skywalker being Vader.

Comment: Ok, could you please take off the flag and put this as an answer

Comment: Out of universe = Lucas is not a great story-teller and back-pedals a lot. If George was a rapper he might be named Sir Ret-ConsALot.

Comment: To be fair, I think R2-D2 did try to tell people, many times, but [no one understood him](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8220/why-cant-r2-d2-talk).

Comment: C3PO Had his memory wiped at the end of ROTS

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/R2-D2):

> Organa entrusted R2-D2 and C-3PO to Raymus Antilles, the Captain of
>   the Tantive IV, who was instructed to treat them well and to wipe
>   C-3PO's memory. Although R2-D2's inability to speak basic spared him
>   from experiencing a memory wipe, it did undergo reprogramming to
>   restrict access to the holo-recordings of Leia's birthparents,
>   including Skywalker choking Amidala and her deathbed during delivery,
>   to ensure that Leia's true parentage remained a secret.

I think for C-3PO the situation is clear: After his memory wipe he shouldn't have been able to remember that Vader was Anakin. For R2-D2 it is very likely that the reprogramming prevented him from telling Luke about Skywalker being Vader.

Comment: It is quite explicitly-stated, actually, that R2-D2 *can* tell Luke who his father is, but chooses not to due to his "owner-protection protocols." In other words, he knows that the knowledge that his father murdered his mother would hurt Luke, and therefore doesn't tell him. This is in *The Swarm War*, the last book in the uninspiring *Dark Nest Trilogy*.

Comment: @JamesSheridan Very interesting. This comment is worthy of being an answer of its own.

Comment: I wish I could, but I no longer own that book. If someone else here does, feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: Wookiepedia isn't an official source; if they have sourced the information that you are quoting, you should use their source as your source. In this case, the passage you quoted is no longer present, so it's impossible to verify. It's also a frankly ridiculous premise. R2 can't speak Basic, so he'll never tell? We'll just torture him with these memories he can never speak of for all eternity or until he jumps into a swamp to try and end it all?

Answer (score 2):

R2-D2 and C3P-O had their memories wiped by Captain Antilles shortly after the birth of both Luke and Leia.  If not R2-D2, then at least C3P-O did.

From a [scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=73E9WD5gi_I) in *Revenge of the Sith*:

> **Senator Bail Organa**:  Captain Antilles?
>
> **Captain Antilles**:  Yes, your Highness?
>
> **Senator Bail Organa**:  I'm delivering these two droids into your care.
>   Treat them well, clean them up and get the protocol droid's mind
>   wiped.
>
> **C3P-O**:  What?!?!
>
> **R2-D2**:  [Beeps] ... [Chuckling beeps] (I assume R2-D2 says somwthing like "Me too?!  We aren't going
>   to remember anything?!")
>
> **C3P-O**: Ohhh nooo!

Comment: What exactly are you quoting from here?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet it's from RotS, see edit.

Comment: Only C-3PO's memory was wiped. see [why-was-c3pos-memory-wiped-but-not-r2d2s](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55619/why-was-c3pos-memory-wiped-but-not-r2d2s)