# Star Wars Episode 5, R2D2's memory

Tags: star-wars, yoda, r2-d2

I was watching Episode 5 recently and something strange come to my eye. When Luke arrives at Dagobah it seems that neither Yoda and R2D2 seems to remember each other.

As far as I know R2D2 never had a memory wipe according to Star Wars wikis and this question: [Why was C-3PO's memory wiped, but not R2-D2's?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55619/why-was-c3pos-memory-wiped-but-not-r2d2s)

I don't know if R2D2 knew Yoda personally but he should have known him. For Yoda it maybe was just another R2 unit.

Is there a universe (Legends or extended) explanation why R2D2 seem to doesn't know him?

Comment: Don’t start looking for inconsistencies between the prequels and original trilogy, you’ll never stop finding them. You’ll equally find as many fan theories trying to hand-wave them away. The only one you need though is that Lucas just didn’t care enough/was a good enough film maker.